# How to convert remotemessage to notificationmessage

Tags: android

In SFMC we have default messageservice which is integrated inside the library which will handle onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage rm)., where as in SFMC inside our app how we will change remotemessage to notificationmessage in  android.

Here is the more details why we want to change the RemoteMessage to NotificationMessage. we have used customized notification flow in our application , where as in that we have NotificationMessage class. And also for customized notification flow we will not have FireBaseMessagingService., which is inside the SFMC library.

Comment: This is _not_ a Marketing Cloud, or any other Salesforce product issue.  This is 100% your implementation with Google's FirebaseMessaging and what you're trying to accomplish can be done with or without any of Salesforce's products in your application.  Refer to Google's documentation on setting up an appropriate receiver for your notifications, handle them and simply do not pass them along.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to parse `rm.getData()` into the notification elements, but this has *nothing* to do with Marketing Cloud.  See https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/kotlin/MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt#L55